# TypeScript - duplicate identifier in lib.ts

Tags: visual-studio, jspm

I'm trying to get started with jspm and Visual Studio. (and Aurelia JS)

In package.json I have...

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "src/main.js",
  "devDependencies": {
  "ts": "github:frankwallis/plugin-typescript@^2.4.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "typescript": "npm:typescript@^1.6.2"
}
```

On compile I get about 11k "Duplicate identifier errors" pointing at at the jspm Typescript package lib.core.d.ts.

I suppose there's another lib.ts somewhere else, but I have no idea where.

This is a Cordova project in VS, not sure if that makes any difference.

Comment: How did you solve your problem?

Comment: Visual Studio has its own version of TypeScript installed, and then jspm package of TypeScript was installed as well, and they both have competing lib.d.ts files. I uninstalled that package because I don't actually need it and use VS for compiling the TypeScript.